# Laravel: Filter collection on property, with a twist

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-collection

I am looking for an elegant (and comprehensible in a year's time) solution for a collection filtering challenge.
I am querying a log database and get some sort of the following data structure

```
| refId   | isDeleted   | loggedDate          |
|---------|-------------|---------------------|
| 1       | 0           | 2018-02-23 21:39:05 |
| 2       | 0           | 2018-02-23 21:39:05 |
| 3       | 0           | 2018-02-23 21:39:05 |
| 4       | 0           | 2018-02-23 21:39:05 |
| 2       | 1           | 2018-02-23 21:49:05 |
| 5       | 0           | 2018-02-23 21:49:05 |
| 6       | 1           | 2018-02-23 21:49:05 |
```

My objective is to filter out the entries which have both, `isDeleted=0` && `isDeleted=1`, and to leave only those which are either `isDeleted=0` or `isDeleted=1`. In this example I should end up with datasets of 1, 3, 4, 5 and 6.

Thx.

PS. The collection might hold up to 1000 entries, if you were to ask...

Comment: Can there be multiple 1 and 0 entries for each refId, or just one of each?

Comment: Ideally, there can be multiple isDeleted=0 for an entry but only one isDeleted=1 for each entry (when it is deleted, it's gone for good).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could [group by](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-groupby) `refId` and `isDeleted` and filter the groups that only have one entry.

```
$refIds = $collection->groupBy(['refId', 'isDeleted'])->filter(function($refGroup) {
    return count($refGroup) === 1;
});
```

I can't currently test this to verify it works, I just tried to come up with an approximation for how I would do this in SQL based on the Laravel docs.

The result would still be grouped though, so it might not be that handy depending on how you're using it.

Comment: Well, we have a winner! BTW, to ungroup the result I've chained `->flatten(1)` to the expression.

Comment: Ah, good idea. I'm glad it worked for you! I'd like to add, this will probably perform better if it's possible to move this logic to the query rather than doing it on the collection.

Comment: I was too quick to celebrate. The final collection is empty, when grouped and filtered by both keys... However, I like the direction of thought, so that‘s at least an upvote.

Comment: Re-marking this as correct answer for inspiration. The working answer is the other one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **Don't Panic** advice, I've come up with the following chain.

```
$collection->groupBy('refId')
                ->filter( function($refGroup) {
                    if ( $refGroup->count() > 1 ) {

                        # 0 + 1
                        $length = $refGroup->count();
                        $sum = $refGroup->reduce(function($carry, $item){
                            return $carry + $item->isDeleted;
                        });

                        # all sum=0 refIds are OK (no deletions)
                        if ( $sum == 0 ) {
                            return $refGroup;
                        } else {
                            # all sum=1 are good if the length=1 (deleted once)
                            if ( $length == $sum ) {
                                return $refGroup;
                            } else {
                                # sum=1 and length more than 1? manipulated and deleted => ignore
                                return false;
                            }
                        }

                    } else {
                        return $refGroup;
                    }
                })
                ->flatten(1)
                ->unique('refId');
```

The first tests are OK. Will need to test it with different datasets, though.